# shared boundaries of contours in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am converting an image(full-pixel semantic segmentation mask) with each object corresponding to a constant color(no illumination or other effects; aliased image) to find the contour of each object. Ideally, I am expecting a shared boundary between adjacent objects.

My current approach does not provide a shared boundary because I am isolating each connected component. The solution has boundaries overlapping with between adjacent contours. Can you suggest an approach for shared boundaries?

Approach:

- Create a mask for each of the unique colors.
- Find the connected components for each of the object in the mask
- Find the contour for each connected component.

input image-https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-12gVzPUueXSOpg4EOSRxi1Dx2nBIFQ9/view?usp=sharing

output image generated from contours(identical to the input but has overlapping contours)-https://drive.google.com/file/d/19WzIVe3iXU6IibEojNgHlEaNO3FuLgdW/view?usp=sharing

overlapping contours in the red doodle, see yellow and green-https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g02cvbwS1toNIbj4icZunRx70I-6i923/view?usp=sharing

image generated from contours looks similar but the below image shows the overlapping contours

Comment: Fix link to the output image

Comment: fixed the image.thanks! @Nuzhny